# The script is not cycling through the images

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically the problem is that the code is not cycling through the images correctly. In my personal analysis I believe it has something to do with the slideshow function using css. FYI it shows the first image but does not cycle through.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "Picture1.png
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "Picture2.png"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "Picture3.png"
var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "Picture2.png"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="Picture1.png" width="500" height="300" name="slide" /></p>



<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image2"+step+".src");
            if(step<4)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout(slideit,3000);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: "image2" + step => "image" + step

Comment: using eval is not considered a good practice because it is expensive as its not optimized and is a security risk. You should consider avoiding it. Read the don't use eval needlessly part here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = [];
for(var i=0; i<4; i++) images.push( "Picture"+ ( i + 1 ) +".png" );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="Picture1.png" width="500" height="300" name="slide"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=0;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = images[step++];
            step = step % 4;
        }
        window.setInterval(slideit,3000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```